# p4v: You need to get version 2.0 (or later) of PyGTK for this to work

Tags: pygtk, p4v

I installed p4vasp and I am getting an error which I am not able to resolve.

```
You need to get version 2.0 (or later) of PyGTK for this to work. You
             can get source code from http://www.pygtk.org
```

I have also attached diagnostic script. Kindly help me with the installation of pyGTK. I installed the same but still getting the same error.

I guess python different versions are causing the error. But I don't know how to resolve it.